# numpy converting data into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an extract from the database, the data is delimiter by "|" I trying  to load this to numpy array to perform some filtering. For example save into file only lines which contains in 3th column LOGOUT. I started from load example.txt file using:

```
import numpy as np


data = np.genfromtxt('example.txt',
                 skip_header=1,
                 skip_footer=1,
                 names=True,
                 dtype=None,
                 delimiter='|',
                 encoding='utf-8',
                 filling_values=None)
```

but I get the error:

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #3 (got 14 columns instead of 13)
Line #4 (got 14 columns instead of 13)
Line #5 (got 14 columns instead of 13)
```

data in txt file is:

```
|ID|TIMESTAMP|EVENT_DATE|GROUP|EVENT|CHANNEL|WERT|WERTY|WERTY|SESSION_ID|IP|WERT|DATA|
|5818221|2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00|2021-03-15|LOGIN|SESSION-EXPIRE||qweqwewqewqewqe|qweqewqewqwqeqw|STANDARD|lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD|qwewqeq||weqeqewqewe
|5818222|2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00|2021-03-15|LOGOUT|SESSION-EXPIRE||qweqwewqewqewqe|qweqewqewqwqeqw|STANDARD|lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD||qweqe|weqeqewqewe
|5818222|2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00|2021-03-15|LOGOUT|SESSION||qweqwewqewqewqe|qweqewqewqwqeqw|STANDARD|lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD|qweqe||weqeqewqewe
|5818221|2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00|2021-03-15|LOGOUT|SESSION-EXPIRE||qweqwewqewqewqe|qweqewqewqwqeqw|STANDARD|lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD|||weqeqewqewe
|5818221|2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00|2021-03-15|LOGIN|SESSION-EXPIRE||qweqwewqewqewqe|qweqewqewqwqeqw|STANDARD|lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD|||weqeqewqewe
|5818221|2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00|2021-03-15|LOGIN|SESSION-EXPIRE||qweqwewqewqewqe|qweqewqewqwqeqw|STANDARD|lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD|qweqwe|wqewqe|weqeqewqewe
```

each line contains no more than 13 elements.. what I'm i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in `example.txt`, you can do:

```
with open('example.txt') as fp:
    lines = fp.read().splitlines()
data = [x.split('|')[1:] for x in lines][1:]
```

where the indexing is used to discard the header and empty column. You will get a two-dimensional array containing the data in the file. If you need it as a Numpy array, do `np.array(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, the reason why the problem is shown only on line 3,4,5 is because of the `skip_header`, `skip_footer`

whithout the `skip_footer`:

```
import numpy as np


data = np.genfromtxt('example.txt',
                 skip_header=1,
                 names=True,
                 dtype=None,
                 delimiter='|',
                 encoding='utf-8',
                 filling_values=None)
```

Error:

```
    Line #3 (got 14 columns instead of 13)
    Line #4 (got 14 columns instead of 13)
    Line #5 (got 14 columns instead of 13)
    Line #6 (got 14 columns instead of 13)
    Line #7 (got 14 columns instead of 13)
```

So first, the `skip_header` value should be 0.
Result :

```
data = np.genfromtxt('example.txt',
                 names=True,
                 dtype=None,
                 delimiter='|',
                 encoding='utf-8',
                 filling_values=None)
```

Result:

```
array([(False, 5818221, '2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00', '2021-03-15', 'LOGIN', 'SESSION-EXPIRE', False, 'qweqwewqewqewqe', 'qweqewqewqwqeqw', 'STANDARD', 'lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD', 'qwewqeq', '', 'weqeqewqewe'),
       (False, 5818222, '2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00', '2021-03-15', 'LOGOUT', 'SESSION-EXPIRE', False, 'qweqwewqewqewqe', 'qweqewqewqwqeqw', 'STANDARD', 'lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD', '', 'qweqe', 'weqeqewqewe'),
       (False, 5818222, '2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00', '2021-03-15', 'LOGOUT', 'SESSION', False, 'qweqwewqewqewqe', 'qweqewqewqwqeqw', 'STANDARD', 'lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD', 'qweqe', '', 'weqeqewqewe'),
       (False, 5818221, '2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00', '2021-03-15', 'LOGOUT', 'SESSION-EXPIRE', False, 'qweqwewqewqewqe', 'qweqewqewqwqeqw', 'STANDARD', 'lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD', '', '', 'weqeqewqewe'),
       (False, 5818221, '2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00', '2021-03-15', 'LOGIN', 'SESSION-EXPIRE', False, 'qweqwewqewqewqe', 'qweqewqewqwqeqw', 'STANDARD', 'lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD', '', '', 'weqeqewqewe'),
       (False, 5818221, '2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00', '2021-03-15', 'LOGIN', 'SESSION-EXPIRE', False, 'qweqwewqewqewqe', 'qweqewqewqwqeqw', 'STANDARD', 'lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD', 'qweqwe', 'wqewqe', 'weqeqewqewe')],
      dtype=[('ID', '?'), ('TIMESTAMP', '<i4'), ('EVENT_DATE', '<U25'), ('GROUP', '<U10'), ('EVENT', '<U6'), ('CHANNEL', '<U14'), ('WERT', '?'), ('WERTY', '<U15'), ('WERTY_1', '<U15'), ('SESSION_ID', '<U8'), ('IP', '<U22'), ('WERT_1', '<U7'), ('DATA', '<U6'), ('f0', '<U11')])
```

The reason why first column values are `False` and `dtype` are wrong is because the first line of the txt file contain more delimiter than other lines

```
>>>line0= "|ID|TIMESTAMP|EVENT_DATE|GROUP|EVENT|CHANNEL|WERT|WERTY|WERTY|SESSION_ID|IP|WERT|DATA|"
>>>line1 = 
"|5818221|2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00|2021-03-15|LOGIN|SESSION-EXPIRE||qweqwewqewqewqe|qweqewqewqwqeqw|STANDARD|lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD|qwewqeq||weqeqewqewe"
>>>delimiter  = '|'
>>>line0.count(delimiter)
14
>>>line1.count(delimiter)
13
```

Solution:
For 1 delimiter we have 2 informations, here we have 13 informations so we need only 12 delimiters, finally:
txt file:

```
ID|TIMESTAMP|EVENT_DATE|GROUP|EVENT|CHANNEL|WERT|WERTY|WERTY|SESSION_ID|IP|WERT|DATA
5818221|2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00|2021-03-15|LOGIN|SESSION-EXPIRE||qweqwewqewqewqe|qweqewqewqwqeqw|STANDARD|lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD|qwewqeq||weqeqewqewe
5818222|2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00|2021-03-15|LOGOUT|SESSION-EXPIRE||qweqwewqewqewqe|qweqewqewqwqeqw|STANDARD|lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD||qweqe|weqeqewqewe
5818222|2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00|2021-03-15|LOGOUT|SESSION||qweqwewqewqewqe|qweqewqewqwqeqw|STANDARD|lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD|qweqe||weqeqewqewe
5818221|2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00|2021-03-15|LOGOUT|SESSION-EXPIRE||qweqwewqewqewqe|qweqewqewqwqeqw|STANDARD|lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD|||weqeqewqewe
5818221|2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00|2021-03-15|LOGIN|SESSION-EXPIRE||qweqwewqewqewqe|qweqewqewqwqeqw|STANDARD|lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD|||weqeqewqewe
5818221|2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00|2021-03-15|LOGIN|SESSION-EXPIRE||qweqwewqewqewqe|qweqewqewqwqeqw|STANDARD|lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD|qweqwe|wqewqe|weqeqewqewe
```

code:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('d2.txt',names=True,dtype=None,delimiter='|',encoding='utf-8',filling_values=None,skip_header=0)
```

Result:

```
array([(5818221, '2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00', '2021-03-15', 'LOGIN', 'SESSION-EXPIRE', False, 'qweqwewqewqewqe', 'qweqewqewqwqeqw', 'STANDARD', 'lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD', 'qwewqeq', '', 'weqeqewqewe'),
       (5818222, '2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00', '2021-03-15', 'LOGOUT', 'SESSION-EXPIRE', False, 'qweqwewqewqewqe', 'qweqewqewqwqeqw', 'STANDARD', 'lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD', '', 'qweqe', 'weqeqewqewe'),
       (5818222, '2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00', '2021-03-15', 'LOGOUT', 'SESSION', False, 'qweqwewqewqewqe', 'qweqewqewqwqeqw', 'STANDARD', 'lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD', 'qweqe', '', 'weqeqewqewe'),
       (5818221, '2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00', '2021-03-15', 'LOGOUT', 'SESSION-EXPIRE', False, 'qweqwewqewqewqe', 'qweqewqewqwqeqw', 'STANDARD', 'lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD', '', '', 'weqeqewqewe'),
       (5818221, '2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00', '2021-03-15', 'LOGIN', 'SESSION-EXPIRE', False, 'qweqwewqewqewqe', 'qweqewqewqwqeqw', 'STANDARD', 'lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD', '', '', 'weqeqewqewe'),
       (5818221, '2021-03-15T18:18:20+01:00', '2021-03-15', 'LOGIN', 'SESSION-EXPIRE', False, 'qweqwewqewqewqe', 'qweqewqewqwqeqw', 'STANDARD', 'lAkpligg11Ds9nJGFRPdeD', 'qweqwe', 'wqewqe', 'weqeqewqewe')],
      dtype=[('ID', '<i4'), ('TIMESTAMP', '<U25'), ('EVENT_DATE', '<U10'), ('GROUP', '<U6'), ('EVENT', '<U14'), ('CHANNEL', '?'), ('WERT', '<U15'), ('WERTY', '<U15'), ('WERTY_1', '<U8'), ('SESSION_ID', '<U22'), ('IP', '<U7'), ('WERT_1', '<U6'), ('DATA', '<U11')])
```

Comment: Thanks Aziz it helps me a lot! :) do you know how can i filer it ? I wabt to create array witch contains only rows with LOGIN phrase

Comment: @harveeey
you can do this:
`data[data['GROUP'] == 'LOGOUT']`

Comment: sorry for nooby questions but I'm trying rows = data[data['GROUP'] == 'LOGIN'] and i want to print it by print(rows) and Im' receiving [] empty array :(